# CSS broken for login form under answer form

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, user-interface, login

There is some issue with the social media login icons. It looks like this on SO:

> [image: broken social media icons for login]

It should look like this (screenshot taken from SU):

> [image: correct social media icons for login]

Comment: What exactly is the issue?

Comment: Earlier they were buttons. I believe there is some issue with the CSS.

Comment: I see. Other sites still have the correct layout, I'll add a screenshot.

Comment: @MartijnPieters can you reverse the duplicate and make the other one point to this one? I think this question is the better one.

Comment: @Stijn: agreed, done.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed in the next build, thanks.

We've started splitting up our CSS into multiple files (so that your browser doesn't have to download and handle a ton of unrelated CSS just for reading a question and its answers), and this particular piece of CSS ended up in the wrong file.